# Turn on PC speaker after resume

Tags: alsa, suspend

After resuming from suspend my PC speaker becomes silent. I need to run `alsamixer` and arbitrarily adjust its volume either up or down for it to come back again. But if I suspend and then resume a second time the same problem happens again.

Any ideas what might be making it silent?

I have already checked the following:

1. `lsmod | grep pcspkr`
2. `~/.xinitrc`
3. `~/profile`
4. `/etc/profile`
5. `/etc/inputrc`
6. `/etc/X11/Xsession`

As suggested below, a useful workaround is to create a hook `/etc/pm/sleep.d/alsa` to run `alsactl restore` upon resuming from sleep. But I still don't know what the problem is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check command line mixer applications like `aumix` or `rexima` - you can hook them somehow the wake-up scripts. Or use `alsactl restore`. The reason is probably a sub-optimal wake-up script.

Comment: Thanks! I created a `/etc/pm/sleep.d/alsa` hook to run `alsactl restore` upon resuming. Now the PC speaker works!